# Activate Selectfield by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 links they fill the selectfield with different option. If are the textlabel is active and somebody click the link selectlist1 or other it must activate the selectlabel. How i can do that?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <script>
   var selectData = {

  "sel1":{
     
    "100":"select100", // selectdaten
  "101":"select101",
   "102":"select102",
    "103":"select103",
     "104":"select104"
 
  },
   "sel2":{
     
  "201":"select201",
    "202":"select202",
   "203":"select203",
    "204":"select204",
     "205":"select205"
 
  },
   "sel3":{
     
   "301":"select301",
     "302":"select302",
   "303":"select303",
    "304":"select304",
     "305":"select305"
 
 
  }
  };
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.selectin', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
      var b = $(this),
          buttonId=b.attr('id'),
          selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
          selectField = $('#selectin');
      selectField.empty();
      if(selectSet){    
        $.each(selectSet,function(k,v){
          selectField.append($('<option>', {value:k, text:v}));
        });
      }  
    return false;
  });
});
    </script>
      
    <li><a href="#" id="sel1" class="selectin">Selectlist1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="sel2" class="selectin">Selectlist2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="sel3" class="selectin">Selectlist3</a></li>
    
    
        <form method="post" name="multiform" id="form8" action="" onchange="toggleRadio();">
            <label for="radio1">INPUT Text</label>
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" checked />
            <label for="radio2">SELECT from</label>
            <input id="radio2" name="select" type="radio" />
            <label id="textLabel" for="textin">Formular
                <input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1" />
            </label>
            <label id="selectLabel" for="selectin">Items
                <select id="selectin">
                  <option selected></option>
                  <option value="6">item 6</option>
                  <option value="7">item 7</option>
                  <option value="8">item 8</option>
                  <option value="9">item 9</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
        <script>
function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
    if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectin').selectedIndex = 0; // clear selected option
    }
    else { // because you got only 2 option you don't have to use another condition
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
    }
}
toggleRadio(); // call the function
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 3 links they fill the selectfield with different option. If are the textlabel is active and somebody click the link selectlist1 or other it must activate the selectlabel. How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code on your selectin click;

```
var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');

if(radio2.checked == false){
  radio2.checked = true;
  toggleRadio();
}
```

This would check if radio2 is checked, if not, it will toggle it and call your function for displaying the select fields. Run the snippet, thanks.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    var selectData = {

      "sel1": {

        "100": "select100", // selectdaten
        "101": "select101",
        "102": "select102",
        "103": "select103",
        "104": "select104"

      },
      "sel2": {

        "201": "select201",
        "202": "select202",
        "203": "select203",
        "204": "select204",
        "205": "select205"

      },
      "sel3": {

        "301": "select301",
        "302": "select302",
        "303": "select303",
        "304": "select304",
        "305": "select305"


      }
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '.selectin', function(event) {

        var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
        if (radio2.checked == false) {
          radio2.checked = true;
          toggleRadio();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        var b = $(this),
          buttonId = b.attr('id'),
          selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
          selectField = $('#selectin');
        selectField.empty();
        if (selectSet) {
          $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
            selectField.append($('<option>', {
              value: k,
              text: v
            }));
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>

  <li><a href="#" id="sel1" class="selectin">Selectlist1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="sel2" class="selectin">Selectlist2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="sel3" class="selectin">Selectlist3</a></li>


  <form method="post" name="multiform" id="form8" action="" onchange="toggleRadio();">
    <label for="radio1">INPUT Text</label>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" checked />
    <label for="radio2">SELECT from</label>
    <input id="radio2" name="select" type="radio" />
    <label id="textLabel" for="textin">Formular
                <input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1" />
            </label>
    <label id="selectLabel" for="selectin">Items
                <select id="selectin">
                  <option selected></option>
                  <option value="6">item 6</option>
                  <option value="7">item 7</option>
                  <option value="8">item 8</option>
                  <option value="9">item 9</option>
                </select>
            </label>
  </form>
  <script>
    function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
      var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
      var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
      if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectin').selectedIndex = 0; // clear selected option
      } else { // because you got only 2 option you don't have to use another condition
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
      }
    }
    toggleRadio(); // call the function
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry Jerdine, now i see that the funktion   document.getElementById('selectin').selectedIndex = 0; // clear selected option   no more work, after change back from textin to selectin its still filled with the old selectable.It will not clear the selectfield any more.  I dont no what happens